# Guardar la ip al enviar un form django

Tags: python, django

Quiero añadir un campo en la clase Post que guarde la ip de la persona que envie el formulario. Este es mi archivo "models.py"

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

He probado a poner `genericipaddress_field = models.GenericIPAddressField(blank=True, null=True)` en el podelo Post, pero evidentementemente no ha funcionado y lo ha guardado en blanco

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No alcanza con tener en el modelo el campo:

```
genericipaddress_field = models.GenericIPAddressField(blank=True, null=True)
```

necesitas también en la vista que guarda el Post obtener la ip del request y guardarla. Por ejemplo yo uso esta función en las vistas que necesito:

```
def get_client_ip(request):
    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if x_forwarded_for:
        ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
    else:
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    return ip
```

Esta función la llamo en la vista que recibe el request con el nuevo post.

Comment: ¿Que es HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR? Hasta ahora, en todas las request que he recibido, la IP estaba en REMOTE_ADDR

Comment: Un request http tiene headers. Uno de ellos es el  `X-Forwarded-For` que Django lo convierte en la clave `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` dentro de META en su objeto request. Para leer más sobre el header te recomiendo que leas el RFC [https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7239].  Además `REMOTE_ADDR`, `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` no son los únicos headers que puden traer la ip del cliente. También existen: `HTTP_CLIENT_IP`, `HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP`, y otros.